# Speed of propagation of unconstrained detonations in atmosphere

Tags: spacex, rocket-explosion

SN4 SpaceX's test tank went boom. It was a mixture of methalox (methane + oxygen). When it exploded it caused a shock front, what was the speed of this explosion?

Do all shock-waves like that travel at Mach 1 and thus limited by the speed of sound in air? With projectiles/aircraft I know you can have an oblique shock and determine the mach number. But the explosion is not a projectile per say and is spherical and thus one cannot determine this from the video footage.

Is it possible that the explosion caused a shock wave exceeding the speed of sound and if so how could one determine it from video footage or other sensors?

Comment: A search of this site for "fast fire" (as opposed to explosion) yields the following: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18141/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38948/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35787/12102), [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18241/12102), [5](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18244/12102), [6](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18337/12102), [7](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24379/12102) I noticed the word "explosion" isn't used, but without a proper one I'm not sure there was enough energy in the acoustic front to call it a shock wave.

Comment: See also [“Pillars of Baikonur” What is the purpose of the hundreds of short, white posts near the Baikonur Cosmodrome launch pad?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28067/12102)

Comment: [What was the cause of the second explosion in SpaceX's pad “Fast Fire”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18141/12102) links to [SpaceX - Static Fire Anomaly - AMOS-6 - 09-01-2016](https://youtu.be/_BgJEXQkjNQ?t=3m39s). While there are a more than one "boom" sounds, they don't seem to rise to the level of a "ka-boom", much less an [Earth-shattering](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/149563/51174) one :-) Is there any evidence that the SN4 SpaceX's test tank boom was stronger and/or faster than this? [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjKSsf4Cp6U) no sound so I can't tell.

Comment: Also see Elon's tweet in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41675/12102)

Comment: This is more about pressure than deflagration speed but you might be interested in it: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150002597.pdf  It does show fragment speeds close to Mach 2.  There's a chapter on Thermodynamics of Fireballs.

Comment: This is more physics than  Space Explo, so you should find useful information on shock wave propagation by looking for books/websites on shock waves in atmosphere

Comment: You may find the following useful:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/242450/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/271329/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/340487/59023

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off a shock or blast front in this case is caused by a shock wave traveling through the air **faster than the speed of sound** (*https://blastinjuryresearch.amedd.army.mil/index.cfm/blast_injury_101/science_of_blast*.) the shock wave is apparent by the low pressure followed by the blast front causing the water vapor to condense in an effect known as a *Wilson Cloud*. therefore the explosion definitely cause a pressure wave that moved faster than the speed of sound. to calculate that speed using the video, you would have to know the distances of nearby objects to the explosion, and use the framerate as a reference for time.(*Distance/Time*)

I do not know how I would find that information, but there is another way to find out by the use of, of course, math. the formula can be found in detail here: (*https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1667908*) You only need to know a few things: 1 the amount of gaseous molecules per gram(as well as their weight) 2 the average weight of the gases 3 the amount of chemical energy in the reaction. Unfortunately here at 4 we have a problem the: **initial density**. (The above formula only measures detonation pressure not velocity and pressure. However pressure and velocity are intrinsically linked, but we run into the same problem of initial density. If you would like to know more about how you calculate many factors involving explosives you can find more here: *https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemical-engineering/detonation*)

the problem is that it's almost impossible to know the density because the explosion ripped open the tanks of fuel and oxidizer. That caused the two to mix to some extent before the ignition source reached the containers. they then mixed more as the pressure waves propagated through the mixture. All in all it's safe to say that the pressure of the tanks is not a good way to estimate the density, as they vented out their contents to the atmosphere at an unknown rate.

That leaves us no real way of knowing the speed of the shock front without knowing the exact dimensions and distances of nearby objects along with a camera looking from the correct angle with a high framerate. I'll give you a pretty good guestimate of around *4400-6000 m/s which comes from an old study that tested the detonation speed of liquid Methalox.

*DETONATION OF LIQUID OXYGEN-LIQUID METHANE SOLUTIONS
A. V. Grosse, A. D. Kirshenbaum, and A. G. Streng
Journal of the American Chemical Society 1957 79 (23), 6341-6342
DOI: 10.1021/ja01580a062

EDIT: As for the comments saying this was a deflagration not an explosion, the oxford dictionary defines deflagration as:

> combustion which propagates through a gas or across the surface of an explosive at subsonic speeds, driven by the transfer of heat.

There was a very clear shock front, and while it is obvious not ALL of the methane and oxygen detonated a good amount did. The shockwave is undeniable proof of that.

Comment: confused at how this got downvoted within a minute of posting lol. I'm pretty sure it takes longer than that to read the whole thing...

Comment: I salute you Fred, thanks for the fix

Comment: Can you explain the relevance of the formula you link to? It seems to calculate pressure, not speed. Without that, the only relevant part of this answer seems to be the one number you quote.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you for that, I kinda rushed to find citations, I didn't realize that it did not calculate velocity. I was taught from the beginning that knowing one, you already have all the information to figure out the other. I added some another link that is much MUCH more in-depth and has resources to learn even more.

Comment: So to make the citation relevant, please tell us how to calculate the velocity from the pressure. Or, if it's not relevant, just remove the whole thing, along with the duplicate part about the cameras. Just adding links is not very good, you need to put the relevant stuff in your answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it is quite relevant. If you were to actually read both of the citations you would understand why. I realized that I had excluded something for a layman to learn to figure out what I was saying themselves, so I fixed it. I apologize for not being your physics professor, but I answered the question as it was asked. I wasn't about to write an entire college level lecture. Everything you need to know how to calculate every aspect of explosives and more is easily accessible from my citations.